# JavaScript Filter Elements with Multi-select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

I've been at this for over a week and I'm still refreshing on my ES6 JavaScript.

I'm using Bootstrap Select for the multi-select dropdown.

Here's the multi-select and search input markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5>Products & Services</h5>
      <select id="filter-select" class="form-control filter selectpicker" multiple>
       {% for item in filters %}
         <option data-filter="{{ item.data_filter }}">{{ item.title }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-filter" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Bootstrap Select is modifying the select input, and creating a dropdown ul with lis:

```
<li>
  <a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-6" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="10" aria-posinset="7">
    <span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span>
    <span class="text">Information Technology</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Posts that need to be filterable:

```
<div id="posts" class="row mb-2">
      {% for post in seq %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 post">
          {# <div class="{% for category in post.meta('categories') %}{{ category.category|url_encode }} {% endfor %}"> #}
          <div data-filter="{% for category in post.meta('categories') %}{{ category.category }},{% endfor %}">
            <div class="content-header-blue round-top-right">
              <h5 class="m-0 pb-1">{{ post.title }}</h5>
              <p class="m-0 orange">{{ post.subtitle }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-body sp round-bottom-left shadow mb-4 p-3">
              <img class="sp-logo" src="{{ Image(post.logo).src }}" alt="{{ post.title }} Logo" width="100%">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                <a class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" href="{{ post.link }}">View Profile <i class="fas fa-chevron-right pl-1"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

JS I have so far:

```
// Filtering

$('#filter-select').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
  let dropdown = document.getElementById('filter-select');

  let items = document.getElementById('posts');

  let item = items.querySelectorAll('div.post');

  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    let filterItem = item[0];
    console.log(filterItem);
    if (filterItem.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(options) > -1) {
      item[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      item[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});

// Filter by searchable input field

let filterInput = document.getElementById('search-filter');

filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterPosts);

function filterPosts(){
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('search-filter').value.toUpperCase();

  let posts = document.getElementById('posts');

  let post = posts.querySelectorAll('div.post');

  for (let i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
    let filterItem = post[i].getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
    if (filterItem.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      post[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      post[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could provide some insight or some code examples that I can go off I would sincerely appreciate it.

I'm currently an ES6 JavaScript course to refresh, I am still learning.

My question is how do I filter the elements clicked/selected within the multi-select dropdown and display the ones that are selected.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I filter the elements clicked/selected within the multi-select dropdown and display the ones that are selected.